# regular expression re.sub for string formatting in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Quite new to regular expressions and am trying to get a grasp on them

```
string = "regex_learning.test"
subbed = re.sub(r'(.*)_learning(.*), r'\1', string)
```

What I was hoping for is `"regex.test"` as an ouput when printing `subbed`, however I just get `"regex"`

Could someone explain why I am losing the .test?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
subbed = re.sub(r'(.*)_learning(.*)', r'\1' + r'\2', string)
```

You can also write it as:

```
subbed = re.sub(r'(.*)_learning(.*)', "%s%s" % (r'\1', r'\2'), string)
```

Comment: Could you explain what is going on with the + r'\2' there? It helps if I can follow along what the script is saying

Comment: `\1` gives you the match captured by the first `()`, and `\2` gives you the match captured by the second `()`. The latter captures the `.text` part of your string. You want the substituted string to be concatenated from the two matches.

Comment: 2 mins and counting! Is there a better way to do this than (.*)?

Comment: @user3234810 : Rather than using `*`, it's generally better to use `*?` which gives you _non-greedy_ matching.  So `(.*)` would become `(.*?)` See `*?, +?, ??` in [7.2.1. Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).